# Accurev hist -c "Comment" not working

Tags: command-line, accurev

I am attempting to search the history by comments in the command prompt but when I do

```
D:\accurev hist -c "My Comment"
```

or even

```
D:\OneOfMyWorkspaces\accurev hist -c "My Comment"
```

It just prints

```
 **** HIST
 ****

    show the transaction history of elements or an    entire depot

 ----- USAGE
 -----

 accurev hist [ -t <transaction-range> ] [ -s <stream> ] [ -c <comment>
 ]
     [ -u <principal-name> ] [ -k <transaction-kind> ] [ -f <format(s)> ]
     { -a | <element-list> | [ -Fx ] -l <list-file> | -e <eid> }
     [ -p <depot-name> ]



 MORE INFORMATION

 Type 'accurev help' for a complete list of topics.

 AccuRev Inc.   http://www.accurev.com   support@accurev.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specify what elements you would like to find the history on:

```
accurev hist -c "My Comment" elem1 elem2
```

If you just want to see the history of all elements in the workspace use:

```
accurev hist -c "My Comment" -a
```